# How to have multiple outgoing connections over bluetooth in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

With my current application, several devices can connect to one device. But the contrast doesn't work. I assume that device A initiated connection to device B. Now if A tries to keep the connection to B and initiate another connection to device C, then the connection of A-B is broken. So is there a way to avoid connection of A-B being lost while connecting to A-C?

Thanks in advance

Comment: my answer on this post discusses this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694840/android-bluetooth-multiple-clients-to-one-host/9695078#9695078 what have you tried so far?

Comment: I used the bluetoothChat sample. Actually I've an array that allows me to store several connected threads. So multiple devices can successfully connect to one device(server). But the contrary doesn't happen as expected. I want to connect device A to B and C without having connection failure of already connected devices.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem with the version/implementation of Android you are using: I have found that it is impossible with certain Android versions (2.2 or lower) on certain devices (Samsung and the Nexus One) it is impossible to run multiple bluetooth device connections at the same time. The exact same apk that works perfectly on 2.3.3 will fail on a Nexus One running 2.2 or a Samsung Vibrant running 2.2. I'd look at the version of Android you are using and see if running on a newer revision fixes this problem for you.

Comment: I'm using Andoid 3.1 Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 3G.
I think as you said IT dépends on thé manufacturer.  I think this is possible with an application i tested: HEYU